# Create AwsCredentialsProvider using Temporary Credentials

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-pinpoint, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I am trying to push events to Pinpoint using Cognito Identity Pool Anonymous User Credentials, but I am not sure how do I convert BasicSessionCredentials to AwsCredentialsProvider?

I assuming AWS SDKv2 Java

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.*;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;

import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cognitoidentity.model.*;


import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cognitoidentity.CognitoIdentityClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.ExpiredCodeException;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.pinpoint.PinpointClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.pinpoint.model.*;
import software.amazon.awssdk.utils.ImmutableMap;

    CognitoIdentityClient cognitoClient = CognitoIdentityClient.builder().build();

    GetIdRequest idRequest = GetIdRequest.builder().identityPoolId(DEFAULT_IDENTITY_POOL_ID).build();
    GetIdResponse idResponse = cognitoClient.getId(idRequest);
    GetCredentialsForIdentityRequest getCredentialsForIdentityRequest = GetCredentialsForIdentityRequest.builder()
            .identityId(idResponse.identityId())
            .build();

    GetCredentialsForIdentityResponse getCredentialsForIdentityResponse = cognitoClient.getCredentialsForIdentity(getCredentialsForIdentityRequest);

    BasicSessionCredentials awsCreds = new BasicSessionCredentials(getCredentialsForIdentityResponse.credentials().accessKeyId(), getCredentialsForIdentityResponse.credentials().secretKey(), getCredentialsForIdentityResponse.credentials().sessionToken());

    pinpoint = PinpointClient.builder()
            .region(DEFAULT_PINPOINT_REGION)
            .credentialsProvider((AwsCredentialsProvider) awsCreds)
            .build();
```

Can someone guide me here building pinpoint client using Cognito Identity Pool Anonymous User Credentials?

Thanks